# how to parse "as suggested is your best option"

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Consider the following sentence:

> **As suggested is your best option.**

In case the sentence is difficult to understand, consider a context as follows:

> Although further opportunities may arise later, I think, for now, *as suggested is your best option*.

The structure seems natural, at least to me, even if uncommon, but also poses a question I find challenging.

**If the sentence is accepted, then it seems to follow that the phrase "as suggested" functions as a noun. Is this inference correct?**

If so, which rule or principle of grammar directly would support this function?  Otherwise, how does the phrase integrate successfully with the overall structure of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested* is a fronting adverbial phrase, = *in the manner that was previously described to you.*

The subject is “the best way [to do it]”

Subject - verb inversion can occur (mainly with to be) after a fronting adverbial: e.g.

“At the back of the house is a pond.”

(And more poetically, “Long was the road, but dearly did I love her.” though this form is now rare save for a few locative adverbs "There are lions in Africa.")

To Add - there is nothing wrong with **As suggested is your best option** save for the lack of context.

*A: "I've got to smash up this pane of glass but I don't want to be injured. What should I do?"*

B: *"Wrap it in cloth and hit it with a hammer."*

A: *"C, what do you think I should do?"*

C: *"As suggested is your best option."*

Comment: So essentially the sentence parses, at the top level, the same as "long was the road", that is, as *adj*-*verb*-*noun*, a verb inversion of the plainer form, and "suggested" being an adjective, such that "as suggested", being an adverb-modified adjective, similarly functions as an adjective?

Comment: As I see it, (i) If there were quotes (but there aren't), "As suggested" would be an NP (the equivalent of "The thing that A has just suggested"); (ii) if "is" is taken as lexically empty, i.e. merely copulative, then *As suggested* is adjectival; (iii) if *is* is taken as the existential "is" (which it probably is) then *As suggested* is adverbial - it describes how the option exists. I therefore am agreeing with you that *as suggested* = *in that manner* = preposition + NP = modifier.

Answer (score -1):

It would make more sense if you put "as suggested" in quotes or italicized it. Then it would function as a pronoun, referring to the previously suggested option.

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason for this suggestion following from the normal understanding or usage of such representations.